# Is there a provider agnostic way of getting up to date cache statistics in Spring framework?

Tags: spring, caching, statistics, abstraction

Spring provides a useful feature of [Cache Abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

But what I could not find is a **provider agnostic** way to get live cache statistics. Essentially I just want to show a list of all the cache names and their corresponding keys with the count of hits, misses, and sizes (in kb) either on a web page or via JMX. I know Ehcache does provide this feature and if I use [ehcache API](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Ehcache.html#getLiveCacheStatistics%28%29) inside the code I can get it (have already used it in the past). But I believe using Ehcache API inside the code takes away the whole notion of the Spring framework's cache abstraction.

Answer (score 5):

The only common, provider-agnostic thing you have is `CacheManager` interface, which provides the following method:

```
Collection<String> getCacheNames()
```

It returns a collection of the caches known by the cache manager.

Comment: +1 for answering such an old question :) however I was looking for much more than just a collection of cache names like, corresponding keys with the count of hits, misses and their sizes (in kb).